# Double authentication with spring security (with form-login and request)

Tags: java, spring, authentication, spring-security, spring-ldap

I am currently working on a project involving GWT 2.5 + Spring 3.1 + Hibernate 3.10.

The web application is currently on production and has protected resources.
For the security, we are using Spring security 3.1 with LDAP authentication.

We currently have a form-login in which we fill in the username and the password and redirect to the adequate html page (in the success handler) if all is OK, otherwise we redirect to the failure page (thanks to the failure handler).

Now, the client wants to keep this functionnality and add a new functionnality which consists of adding the username and password directly in the URL without passing by the form-login. This will authenticate successfully if credentials are OK, otherwise it will redirect to the failure page.

I've read a lot of things about this subject and i'm not able to have things working.

Here is my existing spring-security.xml file :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- SECURITE                                           -->
<!-- ================================================== --> 

<security:http pattern="/jsp/static/**" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/PIE.htc" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/ConsultationAccords.css" security="none"/>
```

```
    <!--Allow everyone to access the JSP login page -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/auth/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsp/*" access="permitAll"/>

    <!-- Limitation  d'accès aux différentes partie de l'appli, les pattern sont basés sur les déclaration dans le fichier web.xml  -->     
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/consultationaccords/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/DownloadCourrierServ" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.gupId" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/DownloadServ" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/ConsultationAccords.html" access="isAuthenticated()"/>    
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/ExportServ" access="isAuthenticated()"/>      
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/ManuelUtilisateurServ" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <!-- If the user is authorized, he will be redirected to the success-handler.
            The sucess-handler is responsible of interpreting what to do next.
            Same principle with the failure-handler -->         
    <security:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />

    <!-- These are the login and logout URLs -->    
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/app/auth/login" logout-url="/app/auth/logout"/>

    <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/app/auth/login"/>
</security:http>

<!-- Point d'entrée pour indiquer à l'utilisateur qu'il doit s'authentifier d'abord -->     
<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="fr.gouv.travail.consultationAccords.server.auth.GAAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

<!-- Handler appelé si l'utilisateur a été authetifié avec succès -->       
<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="fr.gouv.travail.consultationAccords.server.auth.GAAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

<!-- Handler appelé si l'authetification de l'utilisateur  a échoué --> 
<beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="fr.gouv.travail.consultationAccords.server.auth.GAAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- *********************************                  -->
<!-- ================================================== --> 

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider ref='ldapAuthProvider' />
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- CONNEXION AU LDAP      -->
<!-- ================================================== -->

<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://${ldap.server_ip}:${ldap.server_port}"/>
    <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.user_reader_account}" />
    <property name="password" value="${ldap.password_reader_account}" />
</bean>

<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- AUTHENTIFICATION + AUTORISATION      -->
<!-- ================================================== --> 

<bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">

    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <property name="userSearch">
                <bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                  <constructor-arg index="0" value="${ldap.user_base_search}"/>
                  <constructor-arg index="1" value="(uid={0}@${ldap.domain_name})"/>
                  <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>

     <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <constructor-arg value="${ldap.group_base_search}" />
            <property name="groupSearchFilter" value="(uniqueMember={0})"/>
            <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
            <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>
            <property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true"/>
            <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="${ldap.group_role_attribute}"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

The relevant part of my web.xml

```
    <!-- The Spring Security Filter Chain -->
<filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- Pay attention to the url-pattern -->
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Front Controller for all Spring based servlets -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath:applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml
        </param-value>
     </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<!-- Don't forget to declare a spring-servlet.xml -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is what i have done :

1. Declared and set up a bean which is a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter (with success handler, failure handler, authentication manager, usernameParameter and passwordParameter)
2. Added it to the security-http tag + configuring position to FIRST
3. my web.xml contains the springSecurityFilterChain

My spring-security.xml modified :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- SECURITE                                           -->
<!-- ================================================== --> 

<security:http pattern="/jsp/static/**" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/PIE.htc" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/ConsultationAccords.css" security="none"/>
<security:http pattern="/app/auth/images/**" security="none"/>
```

```
    <security:custom-filter ref="requestAuthenticationFilter" position="FIRST" />

    <!--Allow everyone to access the JSP login page -->
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/auth/**" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/jsp/*" access="permitAll"/>

    <!-- Limitation  d'accès aux différentes partie de l'appli, les pattern sont basés sur les déclaration dans le fichier web.xml  -->     
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/consultationaccords/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/DownloadCourrierServ" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.gupId" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/DownloadServ" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/ConsultationAccords.html" access="isAuthenticated()"/>    
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/ExportServ" access="isAuthenticated()"/>      
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/ManuelUtilisateurServ" access="isAuthenticated()"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <security:form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />

    <!-- These are the login and logout URLs -->    
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/app/auth/login" logout-url="/app/auth/logout" />

    <security:session-management invalid-session-url="/app/auth/login"/>
</security:http>

<beans:bean id="requestAuthenticationFilter" class="fr.gouv.travail.consultationAccords.server.auth.RequestAuthenticationFilter">
    <beans:property name="usernameParameter" value="${ldap.user_request_param_direct_logging}" />
    <beans:property name="passwordParameter" value="${ldap.password_request_param_direct_logging}" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Point d'entrée pour indiquer à l'utilisateur qu'il doit s'authentifier d'abord -->     
<beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="fr.gouv.travail.consultationAccords.server.auth.GAAuthenticationEntryPoint" />

<!-- Handler appelé si l'utilisateur a été authetifié avec succès -->       
<beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="fr.gouv.travail.consultationAccords.server.auth.GAAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>

<!-- Handler appelé si l'authetification de l'utilisateur  a échoué --> 
<beans:bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="fr.gouv.travail.consultationAccords.server.auth.GAAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>

<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- *********************************                  -->
<!-- ================================================== --> 

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref='ldapAuthProvider' />
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- CONNEXION AU LDAP      -->
<!-- ================================================== -->

<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://${ldap.server_ip}:${ldap.server_port}"/>
    <property name="userDn" value="${ldap.user_reader_account}" />
    <property name="password" value="${ldap.password_reader_account}" />
</bean>

<!-- ================================================== -->
<!-- AUTHENTIFICATION + AUTORISATION      -->
<!-- ================================================== --> 

<bean id="ldapAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">

    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <property name="userSearch">
                <bean id="userSearch" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
                  <constructor-arg index="0" value="${ldap.user_base_search}"/>
                  <constructor-arg index="1" value="(uid={0}@${ldap.domain_name})"/>
                  <constructor-arg index="2" ref="contextSource" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>

     <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <constructor-arg value="${ldap.group_base_search}" />
            <property name="groupSearchFilter" value="(uniqueMember={0})"/>
            <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
            <property name="searchSubtree" value="true"/>
            <property name="convertToUpperCase" value="true"/>
            <property name="groupRoleAttribute" value="${ldap.group_role_attribute}"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Is it possible to achieve such thing ? If yes, can you please help me to solve this problem ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define your custom filter

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CustomAuthFilter implements Filter {


    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String username = servletRequest.getParameter("username");
        String password = servletRequest.getParameter("password");
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);
        Authentication successfulAuthentication;
        try {
            successfulAuthentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(authRequest);
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);
            return;
        }
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(successfulAuthentication);
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, servletResponse);

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }
}
```

Define this filter as a spring bean

```
<bean id="customFilter" class="com.example.CustomAuthFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
<bean>
```

Add this filter to a spring security filter chain

```
<security:http ...>
    <custom-filter ref="customFilter" position="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
</security:http>
```

Comment: In fact, i've already tested your solution before posting here but it doesn't work. I don't know why... I have found a solution and i'm going to post it here. Thank you.